Is this bad edge flow in a thumb?
I'm creating a model of a hand. I'm wondering if the edges are all messed up around the thumb. Here's an image that shows the edges that get highlighted when I double click on any of them:

My intuition says that that's bad behavior for the edges, because loop cuts doesn't look like that at all. With loop cuts, the edges form a closed loop. But I'm not sure.
If this is bad, why?
This hand will be animated later, so that's why I'm trying to get good topology.

Check fixing spiral topology.

"If this is bad, why?" - It's bad because it makes working with the mesh much more troublesome. A clean edge loop is "local". You can easily remove it, slide it, or add more in between without affecting other areas of the model. If you have a spiral running from the thumb around the body for example, you can't simply remove it because it affects areas you don't want to change. Furthermore,  the addition of another edge "loop” (spiral) on the thumb also adds geometry to the body where it is not needed.
